# Android Calcluate String from left to right

Tags: java, android

```
package com.javahelps.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import net.objecthunter.exp4j.Expression;
import net.objecthunter.exp4j.ExpressionBuilder;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    // IDs of all the numeric buttons
    private int[] numericButtons = {R.id.btnZero, R.id.btnOne, R.id.btnTwo, R.id.btnThree, R.id.btnFour, R.id.btnFive, R.id.btnSix, R.id.btnSeven, R.id.btnEight, R.id.btnNine};
    // IDs of all the operator buttons
    private int[] operatorButtons = {R.id.btnAdd, R.id.btnSubtract, R.id.btnMultiply, R.id.btnDivide};
    // TextView used to display the output
    private TextView txtScreen;
    // Represent whether the lastly pressed key is numeric or not
    private boolean lastNumeric;
    // Represent that current state is in error or not
    private boolean stateError;
    // If true, do not allow to add another DOT
    private boolean lastDot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Find the TextView
        this.txtScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScreen);
        // Find and set OnClickListener to numeric buttons
        setNumericOnClickListener();
        // Find and set OnClickListener to operator buttons, equal button and decimal point button
        setOperatorOnClickListener();
    }

    /**
     * Find and set OnClickListener to numeric buttons.
     */
    private void setNumericOnClickListener() {
        // Create a common OnClickListener
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Just append/set the text of clicked button
                Button button = (Button) v;
                if (stateError) {
                    // If current state is Error, replace the error message
                    txtScreen.setText(button.getText());
                    stateError = false;
                } else {
                    // If not, already there is a valid expression so append to it
                    txtScreen.append(button.getText());
                }
                // Set the flag
                lastNumeric = true;
            }
        };
        // Assign the listener to all the numeric buttons
        for (int id : numericButtons) {
            findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Find and set OnClickListener to operator buttons, equal button and decimal point button.
     */
    private void setOperatorOnClickListener() {
        // Create a common OnClickListener for operators
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // If the current state is Error do not append the operator
                // If the last input is number only, append the operator
                if (lastNumeric && !stateError) {
                    Button button = (Button) v;
                    txtScreen.append(button.getText());
                    lastNumeric = false;
                    lastDot = false;    // Reset the DOT flag
                }
            }
        };
        // Assign the listener to all the operator buttons
        for (int id : operatorButtons) {
            findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
        // Decimal point
        findViewById(R.id.btnDot).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (lastNumeric && !stateError && !lastDot) {
                    txtScreen.append(".");
                    lastNumeric = false;
                    lastDot = true;
                }
            }
        });
        // Clear button
        findViewById(R.id.btnClear).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtScreen.setText("");  // Clear the screen
                // Reset all the states and flags
                lastNumeric = false;
                stateError = false;
                lastDot = false;
            }
        });
        // Equal button
        findViewById(R.id.btnEqual).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onEqual();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Logic to calculate the solution.
     */
    private void onEqual() {
        // If the current state is error, nothing to do.
        // If the last input is a number only, solution can be found.
        if (lastNumeric && !stateError) {
            // Read the expression
            String txt = txtScreen.getText().toString();
            // Create an Expression (A class from exp4j library)
            Expression expression = new ExpressionBuilder(txt).build();
            try {
                // Calculate the result and display
                double result = expression.evaluate();
                txtScreen.setText(Double.toString(result));
                lastDot = true; // Result contains a dot
            } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
                // Display an error message
                txtScreen.setText("Error");
                stateError = true;
                lastNumeric = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this code to calculate a string but this code calculate the string  without consider of the order of precedence.
Exp 3+3*3 the output 12.0
But I would like to get the output 18.0
Calculation should go from left to right how can I modify this code

Comment: Since your calculation logic is inside your call to the library method `evaluate()` there's not much we can do to help you unless we were to see that code. There are obviously ways to do math calculations with String inputs, but then you would have to roll your own class instead of using the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why someone whould need this but here you go.
 I have a method for you that evalutes an arithmetic string from left to right by using a regular expression that splits the elements in `double` numbers and the four basic operators `+,-,*./`. Then it calculates the result by going throu all parts saving the actual operator and using it with the result and the actual number.

```
private double evalLeftToRight(String text){
    double result = 0.0f;
    char actualOperant = ' ';
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\d*\\.\\d+)|(\\d+)|([\\+\\-\\*/]))");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);  
    while(m.find()) {
        String part = m.group();
        if     (part.equals("+")) actualOperant = '+';
        else if(part.equals("-")) actualOperant = '-';
        else if(part.equals("*")) actualOperant = '*';
        else if(part.equals("/")) actualOperant = '/';
        else{
            double actualNumber = Double.parseDouble(part);
            switch(actualOperant){
                case ' ': result = actualNumber; break;
                case '+': result += actualNumber; break;
                case '-': result -= actualNumber; break;
                case '*': result *= actualNumber; break;
                case '/': result /= actualNumber; break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I think you can use it in your `onEqual()` method.

```
private void onEqual() {
    [...]
    String txt = txtScreen.getText().toString();
    double result = evalLeftToRight(txt);
    txtScreen.setText(Double.toString(result));
    [...]
}
```